# Postgres select json array and remap property name

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I need to remap the names of properties in the objects of an array in `postgres` when performing a `SELECT` query.

The table `user_phones` has columns `id` and `phones`. Imagine `phones` column type is `json` and the array has the following structure:

```json
[
  {
    model: "samsung s23 utra",
    serial_number: 123456
  },
  {
    model: "apple i-phone 15",
    serial_number: 123477
  }
]
```

When I perform the select query I want the `phones` property in the response to be returned as:

```json
[
  {
    model: "samsung s23 utra",
    serialNumber: 123456
  },
  {
    model: "apple i-phone 15",
    serialNumber: 123477
  }
]
```

I was thinking somewhere along the lines of `SELECT p.id, json_build_array(SELECT <this is where I'm stuck>) as p.phones FROM user_phones as p`;

I've added [fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fn18u0FS)

Is there a simple way of performing this in postgres?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve ! the expected JSON is similar to the input

Comment: I'm trying to remap `serial_number` in the objects to `serialNumber` so that it returns the response with the converted property name. But only on a SELECT query. I don't want to change the way it's stored, only the way it's fetched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast to `text`, `replace()`, cast back to `json`: [Demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/F4--NYFn)

```
select id, replace(phones::text,'"serial_number"','"serialNumber"')::json
from user_phones;
```

| id | jsonb_pretty |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [ { "model": "samsung s23 utra", "serialNumber": "12345" }, { "model": "iphone15", "serialNumber": "12333" } ] |

It'll target anything matching the pattern regardless of whether that's actually a key or a value, or a part of either. On the upside, it's way simpler, faster and frees you from worrying about the current and future structure of objects in your array.

If you deconstruct, rename, reconstruct, you'll lose keys and values of all elements which structure you didn't explicitly address, whenever an element has a missing or renamed key, or has some additional data in it.

---

Another way that's free from the downsides of blind text replacement is to use [`jsonb` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) `-` to remove the old key and `||` to re-add it with a new name:

```
select id, json_agg(   e - 'serial_number'
                    || jsonb_build_object('serialNumber',e->'serial_number') )
from user_phones,jsonb_array_elements(phones::jsonb)_(e) 
group by 1;
```

That way you really only rename the key in each object, without any assumptions about the structure around it. Be warned that switching from [`json` to `jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) will compact insignificant whitespace, as well as order and deduplicate your keys.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`json_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function to expand a JSON array into multiple rows, then apply [`json_build_object`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to reconstruct the JSON elements, and finally, use [`json_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-aggregate.html) to consolidate these elements back into a JSON array.

```
SELECT id, json_agg(
              json_build_object('model', value->'model', 'serialNumber', value->'serial_number')::json
           ) new_json
FROM user_phones u
CROSS JOIN json_array_elements(u.phones) 
GROUP BY id
```

Results :

```
id  new_json
1   [{"model" : "samsung s23 utra", "serialNumber" : 123456}, {"model" : "apple i-phone 15", "serialNumber" : 123477}]
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Idl-KWEQ)